AKS - Insights with "Managed Prometheus visualizations" throws access denied error
Had provisioned a new AKS cluster (Visual Studio Enterprise Subscription) and enabled Container Insights along with Managed Prometheus and Grafana.
However Insights for "Managed Prometheus visualizations (Preview)" shows "Access Denied" error, tried to logout/login to refresh token, still got same error.
Anything else I should be looking at?


Check what is your current permission as of now- az role assignment list --assignee <your-username-or-object-id> --scope <monitor-workspace-or-aks-cluster-id>  -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-list-cli

Should I use the below command to get the Managed Identity associated with the AKS cluster?   az aks show --resource-group  --name  --query identity    When I tried with the pricipalID retrived from the previous command to include role assignments, it threw "Cannot find user or service pricipal in grap database...."

Best is keep it simple, go to your aks, under access control (iam) see assigned role + icon, click that, search for the highlighted role which I showed in my answer, assign them. give it 5-10sec for the role to propogate. Done. You can refresh and see. It should show your prometheus data as below. I have even shared the docs for prometheus setup steps as links in my answer, check them. it will ease up your steps. See either portal steps or cli steps.

This is probably due to insufficient permissions for the user or system-managed identities on the Azure Monitor Workspace associated with the cluster. As mentioned in comment, check what permission you have. At least below two must be there in permission to view the metrics
Monitoring Reader or Contributor roles

Create the AKS Cluster with Monitoring
az aks create \
  --resource-group arkorg \
  --name cluster1 \
  --location eastus \
  --enable-managed-identity \
  --enable-aad \
  --enable-azure-rbac \
  --node-count 2 \
  --node-vm-size Standard_DS2_v2 \
  --enable-addons monitoring \
  --workspace-resource-id $(az monitor log-analytics workspace create \
      --resource-group arkorg \
      --workspace-name aksInsightsWorkspace \
      --query id -o tsv) \
  --generate-ssh-keys


Enable Prometheus

Done

